MFA with Microsoft Authenticator
Here is my scenario:

I have an Azure AD (abccorp.local) and a user who is logged on to the current machine. For e.g. azuread\jsmith
In my application when I authenticate this user against my database, I want Microsoft Authenticator to act as MFA.
After successful logon of windows AD 'jsmith', I want to call Microsoft Authenticator to confirm the user via selected mode (code, otp, link, etc)
Once the user has been confirmed via Microsoft Authenticator, he is allowed to enter the application.

Language: C#.net
Is there any solution to it?
